# React Razorpay import gives error how to fix it

Tags: reactjs, react-native, web, razorpay

i added npm install razorpay

`import React from 'react'
import Razorpay from 'razorpay'

function Home() {return ()}
export default Home
`
which gives

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'assert' in '/Users/dev/style-indo/node_modules/asn1/lib/ber'
BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/Users/dev/style-indo/node_modules/assert-plus'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'util' in '/Users/dev/style-indo/node_modules/assert-plus'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/Users/dev/style-indo/node_modules/aws-sign2'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'url' in '/Users/dev/style-indo/node_modules/aws-sign2'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

i added npm install razorpay

`import React from 'react'
import Razorpay from 'razorpay'

function Home() {return ()}
export default Home

It Gives

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'assert' in '/Users/dev/style-indo/node_modules/asn1/lib/ber'
BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/Users/dev/style-indo/node_modules/assert-plus'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'util' in '/Users/dev/style-indo/node_modules/assert-plus'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/Users/dev/style-indo/node_modules/aws-sign2'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'url' in '/Users/dev/style-indo/node_modules/aws-sign2'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

How to fix these errors and get razorpay working

Comment: Please format your question adhere to the guidelines of the community